# FLUTTER Problem with result of get data from web API

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON

```
[ { "TenDantoc": "Khmer" }, { "TenDantoc": "Bana" }, { "TenDantoc": "Bố Y" },]
```

I have written  the code  below:

```
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var test=json.decode(response.body);
      print(test[0]);
   }
```

The result returned will be {TenDantoc: Khmer}

My problem is that I want the result returned to be Khmer but i cannot do that. Please help me.
PS: I have try print(test[0]["TenDanToc"] but result is null.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are getting `{TenDantoc: Khmer}` but you want the value `Khmer`. To do that you can do the following:

```
void main()
{

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> user = [ { "TenDantoc": "Khmer" }, { "TenDantoc": "Bana" }, { "TenDantoc": "Bố Y" }];

 Map<String,dynamic> objectValue = user[0];
  print(objectValue["TenDantoc"]); 
}
```

So here first you use the `get` operator in the class `List` which returns a `map`. Then you can use the variable `objectValue` that is of type `map` to retrieve the value of key `TenDantoc`.

The `print()` method will return `Khmer`

Comment: Exactly I want the result as you said but when I do as you say it returns the error "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'"

Comment: can you show me the code that gives you this error? The code above I tried it on https://dartpad.dartlang.org and it was working

Comment: if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var test = json.decode(response.body);
      var test2 = test[0];
      print(test2["TenDanToc"]);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Because it still not understand what is your object in that list. Just decode that 1 more time:

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var test=json.decode(response.body);
    var test2 = test[0];
    print(test2["TenDanToc"]);
  }
```

Comment: I have error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it out @Nguyen Khoa

Comment: It will work this time in my edit, i have checked with my api. You can't use test[0]["TenDanToc"]

Comment: it still not working @hoangquyy. It will return null. This is my code: if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var test = json.decode(response.body);
      var test2 = test[0];
      print(test2["TenDanToc"]);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }